# iPhone 4 retina launch image in Assets.xcassets results in no launch image with iPad 7.x

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, launch

I have an iPhone app built with `Xcode 7`. Its deployment target is 7.0. At first, when running the app on the `iPad`, there no launch images.

I later solved it by checking iOS 6.0 and Prior so launch images would appear on the `iPad`. But now i get " An iphone retina (4-inch) launch image for ios 7.0 and later is required. " in the `Assets.xcassets`.

Whenever I try to add the images for `iPad` Portrait, Landscape and iPhone Portrait in `iOS 7.0` and later, the error disappears, however no launch images appear on my iPad 3rd gen. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have more than one collection of launch images in your `Assets.xcassets`.

After using the "Migrate" button in Xcode 7.3.1 I unintentionally ended up with two collections, each mysteriously created by Xcode. The original was named `LaunchImage`, the Migrate button also created `Brand Assets` collection. Each held some launch images.

I too got your error:

> Assets.xcassets: An iPhone Retina (4-inch) launch image for iOS 7.0 and later is required.

1. I deleted the `Brand Assets` collection.
2. On `Target > General > App Icons and Launch images > Launch Images Source`, I set the popup to `LaunchImage` rather than `Brand Assets`.
3. Hold down `Option` key while choosing menu item `Product` > `Clean build folder`.

[image]

My `LaunchImage` collection was already populated successfully with all required launch images. That error message disappeared.